# Convert a PHP method to a closure

Tags: php, oop, callback

Is there a way to convert a method to a closure type in PHP?

```
class myClass {

    public function myMethod($param) {
        echo $param;
    }

    public function myOtherMethod(Closure $param) {
        // Do something here...
    }
}

$obj = new myClass();
$obj->myOtherMethod((closure) '$obj->myMethod');
```

This is just for an example, but I can’t use callable and then use `[$obj,'myMethod']`.

My class is very complicated and I can’t change anything just for a closure type.

So I need to convert a method to a closure. Is there another way or should I use this?

```
$obj->myOtherMethod(function($msg) use($obj) {
    $obj->myMethod($msg);
});
```

I wish to use a less memory and in a less resource consumption way. Is there such a solution?

Comment: `Closures` are no performance issue. You can use your tryout. Its ok to make it this way.

Comment: Little note on `use a less memory`. Every copy in php `$var1 = $var2;` is a reference in the first place, as long the content isn't changed. This is a direct copy `$var1 = trim($var2);`

Comment: thanks, so you mean there is no other way around?

Comment: If you classmethod needs an `Closure` as param, then the use of `function($arg) use($obj){ }` is ok here and you dont have to think about `performance` here, in this case it is only `micro-optimizations`. Maybe there is another way, but as long you dont want to change your class, its the best solution i thing, to use `Closures`. And since you have only an example here i can only give an general answer.

Answer (score 15):

### PHP 8.1 update

PHP 8.1 introduces a shorter way to create closures from functions and methods:

```
$fn = Closure::fromCallable('strlen');
$fn = strlen(...); // PHP 8.1

$fn = Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'method']);
$fn = $this->method(...); // PHP 8.1

$fn = Closure::fromCallable([Foo::class, 'method']);
$fn = Foo::method(...); // PHP 8.1
```

RFC: *[PHP RFC: First-class callable syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/first_class_callable_syntax)*

Answer (score 9):

Since PHP 7.1 you can use:

```php
$closure = Closure::fromCallable([$obj, 'myMethod'])
```

Since PHP 5.4 you can use:

```php
$method = new ReflectionMethod($obj, 'myMethod');
$closure = $method->getClosure($obj);
```

But in your example, `myMethod()` accepts an argument, so that closure should be called as `$closure($msg)`.