# How to Convert a Function into a Closure in PHP?

Tags: php

I have function that uploads files to server:

```
function upload() {

    $files = Input::file(self::$filename);

    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
       // Validation
       // Uploading
    }
}
```

So, how to make this function as closure? That after loading it returns  error or success information to output variable:

```
$results = function upload() {
}
```

In `results` should be result array of uploading files. It can be error or success state.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a closure?

Comment: Because I need to save result of uploading in one scope, not for each files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php - convert a method to a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701482/php-convert-a-method-to-a-closure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closure function as like anonymous function,that's haven't name.without name call a function by closure.
example:

```
(function(){
    echo "this line";
})();
```

A closure is an anonymous function that can access variables imported from the outside scope without using any global variables.

```
 $client ="azhar";
    $output = function()
    {
        echo "name is".$client;
    };

    $output();
```

it's a anonymous function its give me error because variable can not call in function but when we use variable that's give me proper result.

```
   $client ="azhar";
    $output = function() use ($client)
    {
        echo "name is".$client;
    };

    $output();
```

that's php closure

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `self::` I assume you expect to run this function from inside a class. But you can't really do this - the function should be defined in the class to be able to use `self::`.

But really, you can just pass it as a parameter.

```
function upload($filename) {

    $files = Input::file($filename); // note, self:: removed

    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
       // Validation
       // Uploading
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And when you need to use it inside your class, call it this way:

```
$result = upload(self::$filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated and Expanded**

This answer addresses the OP's primary question of "How to Convert a Function into a Closure in PHP?" One way involves writing a nameless function and then assigning it to a variable.  Since the OP's upload code is problematic, i.e. a method without a class, I therefore borrow the corrected code of @astax, modifying it for the purpose of illustrating the mechanics of how to create a closure in PHP, as follows:

```
    <?php
    
    $f = function( $filename ) {
    
      $files = Input::file( $filename ); 

      foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
         // Validation
         // Uploading
      }

      return $arrResults;
    };
```

Note the trailing semicolon after the final brace.  Also, the closure definition consists of an anonymous function.  You may get the result as follows:

```
<?php
$arrResults = $f( $filename );

 // or in a class:
$arrResults = $f( self::$filename );
```

Note: PHP does not have named closures, so the function needs to be anonymous.  Usually it is assigned to a variable but PHP 7 provides more flexibility such that you may avoid setting a variable as the following two basic examples indicate:

```
<?php

echo (function() {
      return 2 * 2;
     })(),"\n",


(function(){
         return function(){
           return 3 * 3;
         };
})()();
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/PqaQr#output).

This syntax is possible thanks to the support for function call chaining in PHP 7.

Note: if your code includes a return statement, *when the closure executes*, you may assign the return value to a variable.

Incidentally, two useful articles on PHP's closures: see this [issue](https://www.phparch.com/magazine/2011-2/december/) as well in this [issue](https://www.phparch.com/magazine/2011-2/june/).

Lastly, note while other languages recognize a bound variable with a function as a closure and a nameless function as an anonymous function, in PHP support for each is done vis a vis the [Closure class](http://php.net/closure).

### Caveat:

Care should be taken when creating a closure from the Closure object's fromCallable method since it evidently yields a more restricted closure as the following code demonstrates:

```
<?php
class A {
    private $name;
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$person = new A("Tim");

function test() {
    return $this->name;
}

$f = function() {
    return $this->name;
};
$cl = Closure::fromCallable( $f );
echo $cl->bindTo($person, 'A')();

echo "\n\nBut, Closure::fromCallable problematic:\n";

try {
  $cl = Closure::fromCallable( "test" );
  echo $cl->bindTo($person, 'A')();
} catch (Error $e) {
   echo "Unable to bind closure from callable because: \n";
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

see [live code](https://3v4l.org/qso7b#output)

The error message that results is as follows:

> Warning: Cannot rebind scope of closure created by
> ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosure() in /in/qso7b on line 26
> Unable to bind closure from callable because:  Function name must be a
> string

Comment: So, ` $f` sholud be array?

Comment: @OPV No, the value of $f is the anonymous function also known as a closure in PHP.  If you need to return an array of values, then the return statement would appear in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

For Converting a Function into a Closure in PHP, you can :

Since PHP 7 >= 7.1.0, you can use [Closure::fromCallable()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php)

```
$cl = Closure::fromCallable("upload");
$result = $cl();
```

Before (PHP >= 5.4.0), you can use [ReflectionFunction::getClosure()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.getclosure.php)

```
$reflexion = new ReflectionFunction('upload');
$cl = $reflexion->getClosure();
$result = $cl();
```

Another idea is to construct a new function that call your main function :

```
$cl = function (...$args) {
    return upload(...$args);
};
```